# Cannot use custom tab bar react native

Tags: reactjs, tabs, native

I'm trying to create a custom tab bar using `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` but I can't edit the whole tab bar here's my code:

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderLabel` and `renderIcon` method and if you want to use `tabBar` you need to use `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` instead of `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` like this:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```